# Matlab get single 3d plot of 3 variables against a single variable

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get a 3d plot of three variables against a single variable,

I have three variables x,y and z and i need to plot them against a common one variable. But confused on how to use `plot3()` function for this thing.

```
plot3(minc,meanc,globalmin);
```

The above are the three variables i want to plot against `iterations`.

Comment: Wondering how you can plot 3 functions w.r.t one variable in 3D space. In `plot3`, you can plot 2 functions.

Comment: I guess you rather want to plot 3 curves in one 2D-plot? -> `hold all; plot(x,y1);plot(x,y2);plot(x,y3);hold off`

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/q/24987216/1328439. Without an example it is hard to tell what the OP is looking for.