# Stacking multiple 2D plots into a single 3D plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have multiple FFT plots and I want to show them together in one plot, something like the attached figure.

[image]

I don't have any clue how to start. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What figures do you have? What code do you use to generate the figures?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not so bad to do.    You can use [`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html) to help you facilitate this kind of plotting.  With `plot3`, what you need to do is make the `y` values for each of your plots `z` values instead, and if you want to separate the graphs, you need to vary the `y` values in this 3D plot.  Let's do an example.  Let's say I want to place 4 graphs on a single plot in that fashion.  The graphs are:

- `y = sin x`
- `y = cos x`
- `y = exp(-x)*sin(x)`
- `y = exp(-x)*cos(x)`

As such, you'll have a set of `x` values that are the same for each of the plots.  You'll have a set of `y` values that are going to be different, and is dependent on the graph itself.  You'll make these the `z` values, then for each of these graphs, you'll have different `y` values, but for each plot they will **all** be the same, as you'll want to use these to offset each of your graphs accordingly to separate them.  As such:

```
%// Define the x values
x = (0:0.001:10).';
xMat = repmat(x, 1, 4); %// For plot3

%// Define y values
y = 0:0.001:0.003;
yMat = repmat(y, numel(x), 1); %//For plot3

%// Define z values
z1 = sin(x);
z2 = cos(x);
z3 = exp(-x).*sin(x);
z4 = exp(-x).*cos(x);
zMat = [z1 z2 z3 z4]; %// For plot3

plot3(xMat, yMat, zMat, 'b'); %// Make all traces blue
grid;
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
view(40,40); %// Adjust viewing angle so you can clearly see data
```

This is the figure I get:

[image]

---

The trick is to form the right matrices so that this goes into `plot3` correctly.  How `plot3` works is that you can either place single vectors in for your `x,y,z` values, or you can use **matrices** `xMat,yMat,zMat` instead.  Each column of each matrix of `xMat`, `yMat` and `zMat` denote a **single** trace to be placed in your plot.  Therefore, each column of `xMat` for each signal goes into a single column.  As such, I created **one** vector for my `x` values, and replicated them over for as many signals as we have.  In this case, we have 4 signals.  The `y` values will have to be played with differently.  You need to figure out how much **spacing** is going to be allowed for in between each signal.  I chose `0.001` for each signal.  As such, I've created that matrix, which is stored in `yMat`, accordingly and each column represents either `0`, `0.001`, `0.002` or `0.003`.  The `z` values are going to be your `y` values for each signal placed in different columns, which I created with `zMat`.

You'll need to play around with this to get the right spacing and the right bounds of each axes, but this should get you started.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Ray, that is exactly what I want!

Comment: @Farbod - You're welcome!  I also placed a more detailed explanation of what I did underneath my post.  Take a look at my edits

Comment: @rayryeng, why don't you like the `waterfall` function? Try to replace your plotting code with `waterfall(xMat', yMat', zMat');`

Comment: @anandr - `waterfall` leaves too much white space in the area underneath the curves.  It doesn't accomplish what the OP is asking for... he specifically wants the plot to look like what it seen in the figure, and `plot3` does it nicely.  Good try though.

Comment: @rayryeng, strange but in my case (MatLab R2013b) both plots have the same size and axes limits, they differ only in colors. Or you mean that `waterfall` 'fills' area under each curve?

Comment: @anandr - Yes that's what I meant.  Also, when I try and rotate the plot it becomes very slow.  `plot3` doesn't give me that problem.  Strange indeed!

Comment: @rayryeng, to improve rotation speed switch figure renderer to 'OpenGL' (`waterfall` does not do that). Also the OP's original figure is quite tricky because area under each curve is not filled but still lines that are close to observer block lines behind. It will be quite tricky to reproduce this is MatLab. I updated your answer trying to mimic this feature.

Comment: @anandr - I'll check that out.  In the meantime, since the OP has accepted the answer, why don't we just call it a day?

Comment: @anandr - Please do not edit my post directly as it will be rejected outright.  In fact, I got a notification that you suggested an edit... and it was rejected by reviewers already.  Modifying the post to try and communicate with me is against SO policies for editing posts.  Instead, you can place your own answer to illustrate your point.

Comment: Sorry for that @rayryeng. I forgot about that feature of SO. My intention was not to steal the "accepted answer" from you but to provide some additional "trick" for SO users who learn from questions and answers (as I often do myself). I'll post my code addition separately.

Comment: @anandr - Not a problem.  I know that wasn't your intention and you were trying to help.  I didn't reject your edit though.  It was rejected automatically by other reviewers.  Your suggestions are most certainly welcome.

Comment: @rayryeng what to do if the x-values for which different curves are defined are not exactly same. E.g. x1 = 0:1:10 and x2 = 2:1:12

Comment: @Abhinav You're looking at a `waterfall` plot.  This post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322617/how-to-plot-a-3d-graph-of-2d-fft-tranformations-with-a-changing-parameter/29325233#29325233

Comment: @rayryeng not sure if this will work for me because curve 1 and curve2 are not defined for same values of x. Should I put missing z values in the curves with NaNs and then plot ?

Comment: @rayryeng ok Got it. I just need to use plot3 separately for each curve.

Comment: @Abhinav right I didn't understand what you wanted originally. No problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

To improve readability of the plot created in the @rayryeng answer one may also add white stripes below each line that will block deeper lines (`DZ` controls stripe width which is set to 10% of the Z-axis span):

```
ZL = zlim(gca);
DZ = 0.1*(ZL(2)-ZL(1));
for k=1:size(xMat,2);
    hPatch(k) = patch( ...
        [xMat(:,k);    flipud(xMat(:,k))   ], ...
        [yMat(:,k);    flipud(yMat(:,k))   ], ...
        [zMat(:,k);    flipud(zMat(:,k))-DZ], ...
        'w');
    set(hPatch(k), 'EdgeColor','none', 'FaceColor','w', 'FaceAlpha',0.9 );
end
axis tight
```