# How to plot a 3d graph of 2d fft transformations with a changing parameter

Tags: matlab, fft, dft

I want to make a 3d plot of 2d plots of function y 
where y is the dft of function z with having as axis k(x) w0(y) and amplitude(y)(z), where k is the dft variable in frequency domain and w0 is a changing parameter between 0 and 4*pi/45.

```
n=(0:255);
x1 = exp(n.*(w1*1j));
x2 = 0.8.*exp(n*((w2-w0)).*1j);
z =hamming(256)*(x1+x2);
y = fft(abs(z))
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing to understand. What exactly do you want each axis of the 3d plot to correspond to? For example, (x1, x2, y) or (n, z, y) or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question properly, you wish to have something like this:

[image]

The `x` axis is the DFT number, the `y` axis is a parameter that changes your time-domain signal and `z` would be the **magnitude** of the FFT for each signal.

What you need to do is define a **2D** grid of points where `x` is the number of FFT points you have... so in your case, that'll be 256 points, and the `y` axis defines your varying `w0` term from 0 to `4*pi/45`.  The structure for this grid will be such that each **row** defines one DFT result.

For this, use [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) for that, and you do it the following way:

```
max_dft_number = 256;
num_w = 10;
[w0,n] = ndgrid(linspace(0,4*pi/45,num_w), 0:max_dft_number-1);
```

`max_dft_number` determines how many DFT numbers you want to compute.  So in your case, that would be 256.  You can vary that according to how many DFT numbers you want.  `num_w` gives you how many `w0` points you want between 0 to `4*pi/45`, then [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) gives you a set of linearly spaced points from 0 to `4*pi/45` where we have `num_w` of these points.  I set it to 10 here to give a good illustration.

Once you have this, simply use `X` and `Y` and substitute it into your code above.  You don't define `w1` and `w2`, so I'll assume it's constant:

```
w1 = 0.1; w2 = 0.2;
x1 = exp(n.*(w1*1j)); %// Change - vectorized
x2 = 0.8.*exp(n.*((w2-w0)).*1j); %// Change - vectorized
z = bsxfun(@times,hamming(max_dft_number).', x1+x2); %// Change - make sure hamming window applies over each row
y = abs(fft(z, [], 2)); %// Change - FFT first, then magnitude after.  Apply to each row
```

I had to use `bsxfun` to apply the Hamming window on each **row** of `x1 + x2`.  Remember, each row is a DFT result for a particular `w0` parameter.  I also had to transpose `hamming(256)` as the default output is a column.  `bsxfun` in this case with the use of `@times` will duplicate the Hamming window coefficients so that every row gets multiplied by the same window.  If you provide a matrix to `fft`, by default it applies the FFT over each column of a matrix.  We don't want that, and we want to apply this to every **row**, and so you would need to do `fft(z,[],2);` to do that.

Now, to finally achieve your desired plot, all you have to do is use the [`waterfall`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waterfall.html) function, which takes in a set 2D grid coordinates and the corresponding output in the `z` direction.  It assumes that each row is an individual trace of a 3D function.... just like what you wanted.

So:

```
waterfall(n, w0, y);
xlabel('DFT number');
ylabel('w0');
zlabel('Magnitude');
colormap([0 0 0]); %// Make plot all black
view(-12,64); %// Adjust view for better look
```

We get:

[image]

Comment: In case that i have a DFT bigger than my original sign done with zero-padding this does not work. In that case how am i going to solve the problem;

Comment: What is an "original sign"?

Comment: z =hamming(256)*(x1+x2);

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. What about `z` would not work in a different situation?  Can you further elaborate?  I'm still not understanding what you're trying to ask.

Comment: This does not work and i dont know how to fix it. The reason is that the dft takes ks from 0 to 511 and the signal from 0 to 255.                   num_w = 50;
[w0,n] = ndgrid(linspace(0,4*pi/45,num_w), 0:255);
w1 = pi/9;
w2 = pi/5;
x1 = exp(n.*(w1*1j)); 
x2 = 0.8.*exp(n.*((w2-w0)).*1j); 
z = bsxfun(@times,hamming(256).', x1+x2); 
y = abs(fft(z, 512, 2)); 
[w0,f] = ndgrid(linspace(0,4*pi/45,num_w), 0:512);
waterfall(f, (4*pi/45) - w0, y);

Comment: Ahh my friend.  You need to change this statement: `[w0,n] = ndgrid(linspace(0,4*pi/45,num_w), 0:255);`.  You must make this: `[w0,n] = ndgrid(linspace(0,4*pi/45,num_w), 0:511);`.  Look very carefully at the **last** part of the code.  You also need to change your `hamming` call.  I'll update my post.

Comment: @JohnSig - Please see the updated post.  Simply change `max_dft_number` to 512 and it should now work.

Comment: No the thing with zero padding is that your signal which is z goes from zero to 255 and your dft from 0 to 511. The way you post it my signal will go from 0 to 511 due to n which is some that we don't want. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: @JohnSig - Ok then. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: I can't comment because I don't know what you want.  Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74141/discussion-between-john-sig-and-rayryeng).

Comment: I want to print a 512 dft through waterfall which has occured through 256 signal.
I would really like your help because it seems you know matlab well.