# Using MATLAB to stack several 2D plots generated from .csv into a 3D plot

Tags: matlab, csv, plot

I have code to generate a 2D plot from data stored in several .csv files:

```
clearvars;
files = dir('*.csv');
name = 'E_1';
set(groot, 'DefaultLegendInterpreter', 'none')
set(gca,'FontSize',20)
hold on;
for file = files'
    csv = xlsread(file.name);
    [n,s,r] = xlsread(file.name);
    des_cols = {'Stress','Ext.1(Strain)'};
    colhdrs = s(2,:);
    [~,ia] = intersect(colhdrs, des_cols);
    colnrs = flipud(ia);
    file.name = n(:, colnrs);
    file.name = file.name(1:end-500,:);
    plot(file.name(:,2),file.name(:,1),'DisplayName',s{1,1});
end
ylabel({'Stress (MPa)'});
xlabel({'Strain (%)'});
title({name});
legend('show');
```

What I would like to do is modify the code in order to concatenate 2D plots made from the .csv data into a 3D plot where one of the axis is the index of the .csv in `files` kind of like the picture at the top of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987216/stacking-multiple-2d-plots-into-a-single-3d-plot-in-matlab). I got the idea of using `plot3` from that post but I'm not sure how to get it to work.

From what I understood I need to create 3 new matrices `xMat, yMat, zMat`. The columns of each matrix contain the data from the csv file and the `yMat` contains columns that are just the index of the csv but I'm not entirely sure where to go from here.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should have a look at this question and my answer, it is quite similar to your problem: [How can I plot several 2D image in a stack style in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549733/how-can-i-plot-several-2d-image-in-a-stack-style-in-matlab/35552548#35552548)

Comment: Thanks but the answer by @aero-engy is more along the lines of what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call `plot3` in the loop like something like the following.  Basically change the Y-values to Z-Values.  Then increment Y by one for each iteration of the loop.

```
figure;
a = axes;
grid on;
hold(a,'on');
x = 0:.1:4*pi;
for ii = 1:10    
    plot3(a,x,ones(size(x))*ii,sin(x)); 
end
view(40,40)
```

Modifying your code would look something like the following.  Note that since I don't have your CSVs I can't test any of this.

```
clearvars;
files = dir('*.csv');
name = 'E_1';
set(groot, 'DefaultLegendInterpreter', 'none')
set(gca,'FontSize',20)
a = gca;
hold on;
ii = 1;
for file = files'
    csv = xlsread(file.name);
    [n,s,r] = xlsread(file.name);
    des_cols = {'Stress','Ext.1(Strain)'};
    colhdrs = s(2,:);
    [~,ia] = intersect(colhdrs, des_cols);
    colnrs = flipud(ia);
    file.name = n(:, colnrs);
    file.name = file.name(1:end-500,:);
    plot3(a,file.name(:,2),ones(size(file.name(:,2))).*ii,file.name(:,1),'DisplayName',s{1,1});
    ii = ii+1;
end
view(40,40);
ylabel({'Stress (MPa)'});
xlabel({'Strain (%)'});
title({name});
legend('show');
```

Comment: @enea19  If this fixed your issue then up vote and accept the answer so it doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: I tried to upvote it but it says I can't because I don't have enough rep. I marked it as answered though.