# Create 3D Plot- Depth/Time/Temp From Large .csv file_Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I am trying to create a 3D Temperature plot vs Depth vs Time with a large .csv data-set. The example below is created in matlab. I want a similar output using Python 3.x with reverse scales on the Temperature and Depth axis.
[Example output with a few mods needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVj4K.jpg)

I have started off with the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Get the data (csv file is hosted on the web)

data = pd.read_csv('C;\\Path\\TestData_Temp-Time-Depth_3DPlot.csv')

# Transform it to a long format
df = data.unstack().reset_index()
df.columns = ["X", "Y", "Z"]

# And transform the old column name in something numeric
df['X'] = pd.Categorical(df['X'])
df['X'] = df['X'].cat.codes

# Make the plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(df['Y'], df['X'], df['Z'], cmap=plt.cm.jet, linewidth=0.2)
plt.show()

# to Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(df['Y'], df['X'], df['Z'], cmap=plt.cm.jet, linewidth=0.2)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()

# Rotate it
ax.view_init(30, 45)
plt.show()

# Other palette
ax.plot_trisurf(df['Y'], df['X'], df['Z'], cmap=plt.cm.jet, linewidth=0.01)
plt.show()
```

I am having issues understanding how to assign values from from csv to the x, y, z axis.

The example data I am using is formatted like:

[csv data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI1uo.png)

Example data download: [Download Example Data](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/924e5001ac90d43382a0f1c3680b514920190307174051/be966c)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264205/using-matlab-to-stack-several-2d-plots-generated-from-csv-into-a-3d-plot) question answer yours?